# Mac certificate error on lh3.googleusercontent.com

Tags: macos, ssl, certificate

Below is what I'm getting when trying to reach anything related to `lh3.googleusercontent.com` (i.e. extensions, downloading files from google drive etc.) This happens on all browsers that I have - safari and chrome. I have no idea why it's trying to use a self-signed certificate, nor do I know when and why it appeared in my system. I tried deleting this cert from mac keychain, but it seems that browser is still using it. By the way, my computer shows correct time and date. I've been googling forever, but cannot seem to find a solution.

> Your connection is not private
>   Attackers might be trying to steal your information from `lh3.googleusercontent.com`(for example, passwords, messages or credit cards).
>
> NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
>
> Subject: *.maistas.test
>
> Issuer: *.maistas.test
>
> Expires on: 27 Apr 2019
>
> Current date: 23 Nov 2018
>
> PEM encoded chain:
>
> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
>   MIIC+DCCAeCgAwIBAgIJAM9scUihhU/1MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMBkxFzAVBgNV
>   BAMMDioubWFpc3Rhcy50ZXN0MB4XDTE4MDQyNzIwNTEzMFoXDTE5MDQyNzIwNTEz
>   MFowGTEXMBUGA1UEAwwOKi5tYWlzdGFzLnRlc3QwggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUA
>   A4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQD4FVYnmGD8knKT+tvGCpDv36Hc0Z8jcDTJBOBp4689aWZO
>   oThKrb2MPLlMAiCr13JR3tQczOc858720g1PkWIZkgubPFpPNenSkmw35KzLnelS
>   GsGB6DzrJ3bJknytmCJ0i2FuBGninx+BUfsD3rxjADdgGXWkCMh2CgkoKNK2scp4
>   VNuneOaS6t6iziVke95T5vidYROeC6IQS3bLwKxCSsu0L0CiPTrRmOMpmMbxABHM
>   9IkeYS3Vq2dautjef6ecMLf1eAKJV5AU1mk9CoTfJi8rD5XGS4UH/KMPflQ6LN9v
>   Y9iappB5nVkqzb/vcbvI/MRZ0CphOUJjnxEPnV/hAgMBAAGjQzBBMAkGA1UdEwQC
>   MAAwCwYDVR0PBAQDAgXgMCcGA1UdEQQgMB6CDG1haXN0YXMudGVzdIIOKi5tYWlz
>   dGFzLnRlc3QwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEBAOs9AvDcstu0ROKKPD83YQdO6vUd
>   3xRpsW7tjM0XyDCwL87RWURBa9spZWG0fQgnwAwf5q7ny7V6DAgQvZ0umLp7i3xu
>   Amkd298+JF9xqeOaiVjV2WaS8u7ssCPWAawblfGsRCd8o62l+RVDRG5XKoB+M2Zu
>   LJPGB0Jg0ggkX2XgryRGVIfnRcv2B30kqYnLCGju/Zhb1N03fz6Nf6pW0sdAZyZN
>   OJJwJYEcue0Tp/LfGat2G66Ml3XGrX2EDmq9K5vAzKeR0wZyx3I1qjznbOJdx3JI
>   KCdtK7+WoFsu2ZmoXCKHo0uGld3hLcILt14/jBujS0npKxytwV04SduqA7Q=
>
> -----END CERTIFICATE-----
>
> `lh3.googleusercontent.com` normally uses encryption to protect your information. When Google Chrome tried to connect to `lh3.googleusercontent.com` this time, the website sent back unusual and incorrect credentials. This may happen when an attacker is trying to pretend to be `lh3.googleusercontent.com`, or a Wi-Fi sign-in screen has interrupted the connection. Your information is still secure because Google Chrome stopped the connection before any data was exchanged.
>
> You cannot visit `lh3.googleusercontent.com` right now because the website uses HSTS. Network errors and attacks are usually temporary, so this page will probably work later.